# Check network connection in fragment

Tags: android, android-networking

I tried to check the network connection in my SherlockFragment but the getSystemService() method is not recognized.

Below is my code (from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

```
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // fetch data
    } else {
        // display error
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The method `getSystemService()` is not defined on fragments, so get the activity first using `getActivity()`, e.g.:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                             .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // fetch data
} else {
    // display error
}
```

**p.s**: *additianal note*: if there is a potential risk that the fragment is running without being attached to any activity, check whether `getActivity()` returns `null` first.

Cheers!

Comment: The fragment is attached to an activity. What is the risk if not attached?

Comment: If it is not attached, `getActivity()` might return `null` and consequently `getActivity().getSystemService()` throws a `NullPointerException`. However, it depends where you call this code and how you create the fragments. Nothing to worry about, just keep it in your mind ;)

Comment: @Trinimon Im getting getActivity() null. how to resolve this? In android phone Running andriod 4.0.3 its working fine. but in tablet Nexus 7 running 4.4.1 it returns null. Whats going wrong. y its happing?

Comment: If `getActivity()` returns `null`, this shows that no activity has been attached at that point of time. Did you use it in `onActivityCreated()` or somewhere else? Did you create the fragment solely? You can also try to move your code to the `onAttach(Activity activity)` method of the fragment - here you have the activity available and you don't need to call `getActivity()` at all.

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to use network function code in try- catch. And catch the exception If network unavailable. If you use any network checking code, then also you need to catch the exception. Because You have no other way to check whether it is suceeded or no, means, if the network lost in between the function completes.

Comment: I was searching the same way in first time, finaly i reached in this decesition. I simply shared with you.