# Android - how to Lock screen in fragment during runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to lock screen orientation while loading a webview in a fragment.
I have done something similar in an activity and that worked fine. however when i used the same code in a fragment , i get a waring in eclipse IDE saying *the method setRequestedOrientation is undefined for the type MyWebViewFragment*

here is a portion of the code

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

..............

       ...............

        // lock screen before proceeding
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
             setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        else {
             setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        }

        ............
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             // unlock screen
             setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        }
```

One of the fixes that eclipse suggests is to create a setRequestedOrientation method but i believe there should be a better way.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a related problem with solution here : [Check network connection in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481334/check-network-connection-in-fragment)

my solution was to get the activity using getActivity()

the updated code now works:

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

..............

   ...............

    // lock screen before proceeding
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else {
         getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }

    ............
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         // unlock screen
         getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
```